# Make babel runtime global to different webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Ecosystem details for my web application:

- ES6
- Babel
- Webpack

Our application has its own architecture artifact and then each widget onside the page has its own artifact. Everything uses the above mentioned ecosystem things.

For simplicity sake, lets say I have artifact `Arch` for architecture and `w1` and `w2` artifact for my 2 widgets. If I bundle all these artifacts individually they produce a bundle where the `babel-runtime` is included in all the three bundles. so when I put them together inside the web page I am basically including same piece of code (`babel-runtime`) 3 times.

**Question:**
Is their a way to build each bundle individually but not include the `babel-runtime` code so that I can include `babel-runtime` code globally to be consumed by all the three bundle files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the [CommonsChunckPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin)

The way to use it is as follows, in your webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('shared.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle1: '.src/fileForBundle1.js',
    bundle2: '.src/fileForBundle2.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    commonsPlugin,
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // ...
    ]
  }
}
```

All the shared code will be in the shared.js file, you just have to include this file in every page that has a different bundle.